# Latex appendices

Tags: appendices

I am using a latex template with the following definition of appendix command. Could someone explain how is that to be interpreted?
I understand it is creating a new command named `\listAppendixname` but with no argument? What does this do? What is `\listofappendices` doing with `\listAppendixname` and `\@starttoc{app}` as argument? Finally how is that command supposed to be called in the main body of the text? Thanks!

```
\newcommand\listAppendixname{}
\newcommand\appcaption[1]{%
  \addcontentsline{app}{section}{#1}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\listofappendices{%
  \section*{\listAppendixname}\@starttoc{app}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: There is a lot of code you have not shown. `\listAppendixname` is not defined by the code you have shown, but elsewhere. So no idea about what your template does or how it is meant to be used. --- GOM

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the first line. Here it's how the entire code snippet looks like

Comment: Without a minimal but complete (compilable as is) document to reproduce the issue is hard to say, but I think that you must supply the argument to te first line (e.g., `\newcommand\listAppendixname{Myappendix}`)  and then just type  `\listofappendices` where you want the list of appendices with the title "Myappendix".